# Hotlinking prevention returns 404 error NGINX

Tags: nginx, configuration, hotlinking

Can somebody tell me why this snippet return 404 when I'm trying to access images directly or from the original site (by link).

```
       location ~* \.(ico|jpeg)$ {
            valid_referers none blocked example.com *.example.com;
            if ($invalid_referer) {
                return   403;
            }
        }
```

As far as I understand it should return 403 for non original sites. Why it returns 404? If I disable this snippet everything is accessible again (as normal).

Now it sits inside server block.

Should I put it inside server's block / location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you don't have a `root` directive in your `server` block so nginx is unable to locate the files.

Comment: Yes, I only have one in the / location block. Should I include it in every section? And what is the right place for this snippet, should it go inside / location block?

Comment: Put it directly in the `server` block.